# Comparing impact of one variable on another SAS

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have two variables as below. I want to compare if AverageDrive has any impact on the totalStrokes. I have tried running PROC CORR, but wanted to understand if there is any other test that I can run in SAS which would help me understand the dependency between these two variables?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use PROC GPLOT to generate a scatter-plot. Then check the relationship between AverageDrive and totalStrokes.
2. Fit a linear regression model:
   $$Y=\beta_0 +\beta_1X +\epsilon$$
   where $X$ =  AverageDrive, and $Y$ = totalStrokes.

If the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ is not linear, you need to make some kind of transformation of variables. Also after model fitting, need to check the residuals to see if the assumptions are violated.

The model can be fitted by using PROC REG or PROC GLM, and they have no different in your case.

Here is program, and you can begin from it.

proc gplot data=[your dataset name];
   plot totalStrokes*AverageDrive;
run;

proc glm data=[your dataset name];
   model totalStrokes = AverageDrive;
run;